# Ratchet PHP block editing post

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, phpwebsocket

I have 2 web pages - one where display list of post and another where user can edit post.And If post edit by one user other can't edit the same post, and infromation about editing post must display in real time on the index page.
I use ratchet php and [Push Integration](http://socketo.me/docs/push).
I did subscribe on the page where display all post:

```
var conn = new ab.Session('ws://localhost.test:8088',
        function() {
            conn.subscribe('onEditPost', function(topic, data) {
                // This is where you would add the new article to the DOM (beyond the scope of this tutorial)
                console.log('New article published to category ' + topic);
                console.log(data);
            });
        },
        function() {
            console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
        },
        {
            'skipSubprotocolCheck': true,
            'maxRetries' : 60,
            'retryDelay' : 4000
        }
    );
```

When user begins edit post I send information about it:

```
$context = new ZMQContext();
    $socket = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
    $socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
    $socket->send(json_encode($entryData));
```

So the problem is that I can not notify when user didn`t edit post.
How I can do that?

Comment: for what type of website you are using this system.?

Comment: Simple editor for post, there are not a lot of users there